# Why I have the C3867 error in `push_back` the second element of a pair vector?

Tags: c++, vector

I have a problem of `push_back` of vector in c++ which produced an error of C3867. The code is below

```
vector<pair<int, int>> v0(5, std::make_pair(1, 1));;
vector<int> v1;
for (size_t i = 0; i < v0.size; i++)
   v1.push_back(v0[i].second);
```

I would like to know which part of it produced the error.

Comment: The error is not even on the line with the `push_back`.  Always provide the *exact*, complete error output.

Comment: It's just fine. Either paste the minimal code or exact complier error.

Comment: [Works fine for me](https://ideone.com/ceWzbD) after fixing a typo - `v0.size` needs to be `v0.size()`. That is the real cause of the [error C3867](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-2/compiler-error-c3867?view=vs-2019)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is caused by `v0.size` in the loop, you need to use `v0.size()` instead.